# Excel: Find out if cell contains/includes value from a range of cells

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of job titles (A) and list of phrases (B). For each title in A I want to check if it contains a phrase (any phrase, I don't care which) from B.

```
| 1 |-----Example Column A------|----Example Column B----        
| 2 |    Head of Marketing      |    Senior Developer          
| 3 |  Lead Product Engineer    |    Marketing Manager       
| 4 |     Sales Development     |    Sales Development   
| 5 |  Senior Marketing Manager |
```

In the above example, I want to know that the last two cells in column A contain cells in column B.

I found lots of examples online of how to do the reverse, using * to find if a value is contained in a range. I also found the following three examples offered as solutions for problems similar to mine, but none worked for me.

```
{=MAX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$4,A2))+0)}         
{=MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$4&"*")}
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(B:B,A2),B:B),"")
```

I've also tried writing the contents of each cell in column B to start and end with an asterisk (*Senior Developer *, etc.), trying VLOOKUP, SUMPRODUCT, COUNTIF without success.

Is it possible to do what I want?

**Solution**

Slightly modified Mrig's formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(B$2:B$4,LOWER(A2)))*1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND($B$2:$B$4,$A2))*1)
```

This formula will return the number of phrases matched.

You can put this formula in `IF` if you don't want the count.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND($B$2:$B$4,$A2))*1)>0,"Exist","Does Not Exist")
```

See image for reference

[image]

***EDIT:*** After sorting `Column A` in descending order output I get is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help Mrig, it seems to find some of the matches.

When I recreate your example exactly, it gives the correct answer. However, when I sort column A in descending order column C returns 2, 2, 1, 1.

My real world column A is 60k values, most should have a match but only 80-2k find matches depending on order.

Comment: @baasoti - See edit in my answer. That's the output I get after sorting `Column A`. Is it possible for you to share sample/dummy data so that I can recreate your problem.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me - figured out why it didn't work before.

My sorting issue arose because I also sorted column B (to include a blank cell) so that it added 1 for every cell in column A.

And the reason it didn't find all the matches for my main data is because it contains capitalisation, and the matching seems case sensitive.

I've updated the formula to: =SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(Q$2:Q$343,LOWER(F2)))*1)

It now matches 40k (the ones I've checked so far all make sense). Thanks so much for your help, have really been scratching my head with this one!

Answer (score 0):

Put the following formula in col C for each row in col A (starting at C2)

`=IF(ISNA(INDEX(B$2:B$4,MATCH(A2,B$2:B$4,0))),"","x")`

This is a combination of the `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions. `INDEX` returns a cell within a range based on a count, which in this case is provided by the `MATCH` function which returns the position of a cell within an array by matching against a criteria string.

The `ISNA` function is there to hide the "N/A" output in any non-matching cells and display "x" against any matching cells.

Have a look [here](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/) for a more in-depth explanation.

**UPDATE**

As per the comment below, in order to see if Col A *contains* the text in Col B (rather than being a direct match) then use this formula in col C for each row:

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2,"*" & B$2:B$4 & "*"))>0, "X", "")`

Comment: Thanks for the comment - unfortunately it seems to only mark 'x' for column A when it is exactly equal to a value in column B.

Comment: Ah yes. I misunderstood what you where asking. See the update to the answer. This is also case-insensitive.