# Excel formula to find ColumnA value in CoulmnB that has sentence

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking for a way to find the match in Column A to B and highlight. I tried many excel formulas in the forum but unlucky in getting it work.

For eg..

```
**ColumnA**

John23    
Peter    
Nick5    
Kevin4    
T12345
```

**ColumnB**

```
John23 is outside the yard    
Kevin4 is the famous guy    
ABC is with Nick5    
Who is the person at the door. is it Peter?    
R345 Qrtfjd T12345    
Kevin is not the match    
Only Kevin4 is the match    
John is not the match
```

Comment: Would you be able to show us what your thorough and exhaustive research has found so far? If you can show us the partial solution you're working on, people will be much more inclined to help - effort begets effort here.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44825632/1425848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),B1))),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Worked exactly the way i wanted and been looking for. You must be a genius excel guru. Thanks a lot !!.