# Excel: Find particular (text) value in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm struggling with something I think should be easy, it seems to be a common problem, I've found [another solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825632/excel-find-out-if-cell-contains-includes-value-from-a-range-of-cells) on the website but it won't work here in my document.

I want to find the (exact) value into a range, and having a true or false result if this value was found.
I tried with the combination of the find, isnumber and sumproduct formula but the value is never found, if I use a nested if formula it's working.

[image: screenshot]

I have a dutch version of Excel, that's why you see "onwaar / waar" but onwaar is "false" and waar is "true".
Also my formula is written in dutch, but I translated it through the Excel-Translator.de website, I'm not 100% sure if it's done correctly.

In cell F2 I have this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(E2, $A$2:$A$11))>0
```

In cell G2 I have this formula:

```
=IF(E2=$A$2,TRUE,
IF(E2=$A$3,TRUE,
IF(E2=$A$4,TRUE,
IF(E2=$A$5,TRUE,
IF(E2=$A$6,TRUE,
IF(E2=$A$7,TRUE,
IF(E2=$A$8,TRUE,
IF(E2=$A$9,TRUE,
IF(E2=$A$10,TRUE,
IF(E2=$A$11,TRUE,FALSE))))))))))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not do something like if(iferror(vlookup(e2,A2:A100,1,0)>0,0),True,false)

Comment: Just use `COUNTIF()` e.g. `=AANTAL.ALS(A$2:A$11;E2)>0`

Comment: @JvdV thank you, this did the job (and with translated formula too ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use function `=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$11,A2)` to know if the search value column contains your value.

Then, use function `=IF(F2>=1,"True","False")` determine true or false.

Combined, yout get `=IF((COUNTIF($E$2:$E$11,A2)),"True","False")`

[screenshot of working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9NAP.png)